# Using System.Net.Mail to send emails - using the synchronous method 'Send' works, but 'SendAsync' does not

Tags: asynchronous, f#, smtp

I'm trying to send emails using F#, and found a code snippet that seems to work when using `Send`. I'm using gmail accounts and made sure that the sender account enables less secure apps to use it and that the email & password combo is correct. I'm also using port `587`. `SendAsync` does not seem to work, but it's also not throwing any exceptions which seems strange.

```
let sendMailMessage email topic msg =
    let msg = new MailMessage(sender, email, topic, msg)
    msg.IsBodyHtml <- false

    let client = new SmtpClient(server, port)
    client.EnableSsl <- true
    client.UseDefaultCredentials <- false
    client.Credentials <- System.Net.NetworkCredential(sender, password)

    client.SendCompleted |> Observable.add(fun e ->
        let msg = e.UserState :?> MailMessage
        if e.Cancelled then
            ("Mail message cancelled:\r\n" + msg.Subject) |> Console.WriteLine
        if e.Error <> null then
            ("Sending mail failed for message:\r\n" + msg.Subject + ", reason:\r\n" + e.Error.ToString()) |> Console.WriteLine
        if msg <> Unchecked.defaultof<MailMessage> then
            msg.Dispose()
        if client<>Unchecked.defaultof<SmtpClient> then
            client.Dispose()
    )

    try
        client.SendAsync(msg, msg) // runs fine but doesn't actually send an email
        client.Send(msg) // this works, but it's also blocking
    with
    | e -> printfn "%A" e
```

I'm wondering if I'm doing anything wrong. I'm currently straight up calling the function from main in a test project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your program is probably exiting before `SendAsync` finishes. Just as a test, try putting a `Console.ReadLine` at the end of `main` to prevent premature exit.

Comment: You're right, that was the problem. I should keep that in mind when testing async functions.

Answer (score 2):

Since `client.SendAsync(msg, msg)` returns a `Task` you need to await and block on that when you're in a synchronous function, e.g. like this:

```
client.SendAsync(msg, msg)
|> Async.AwaitTask // Converts Task<> to Async<>
|> Async.RunSynchronously // Blocks until the async work is done.
```